# Can't boot and stuck on BusyBox

Tags: linux-mint, boot, mdadm, initramfs, busybox

When i try to boot on my Linuxmint laptop, i'm stuck on BusyBox with this message

```
-Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
  -Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
-Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/mapper/vgmint-root does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
```

I got the same problem before, after a kernel update. As I had other worries  I reinstalled Linuxmint from scratch. But this new installation has only booted once before this same issue.

I checked the known problems so:

`cat /proc/cmline` returns:
`BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.15.0-58-generic root=/dev/mapper/vgmint-root ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7`

`cat /proc/modules; ls /dev` returns a lot (not empty like similar issues)

Boot with older installed kernels do the same thing (5-15-0-58, 5-15-0-48, ...)

And SATA Configuration is already set to ahci in bios.

edit :
without `quiet splash` flags I now see this message:

```
Lockdown: mdadm: /dev/mem,kmem,port is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

Is this about RAID? I don't think I've set up a RAID at all

Comment: Boot without `quiet splash`, take a decent quality picture, edit your message and attach it.